# Responder Chain (UIWebView inside UItableViewCell) Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, uitableview, first-responder

I've been struggling with first responder problem. I put web controller (`UIWebView`) inside `UITableViewCell`  and now I would like to scroll vertically my table and not affect `UIWebView` (this case may be done by disabling scrolling scrollview from `UIWebView`). However problem appears when user zooms into web content, then I want scroll horizontally through web content and still vertically scroll in table (cause cell will be resized to zoomed content).

Answer (score 0):

There is a property called 'multipleTouchEnabled' that should disable the pinch gesture, but I think the user would still be able to double-tap (assuming the cell doesn't consume this gesture). Why not, instead of creating multiple UIWebView's (which have a large overhead) don't you create one hidden UIWebView that loads a website and caches an image, then load this image into the cell.

Ultimately, if you still wanted to use the UIWebView approach, you could probably subclass it and override hitTest/touches methods or handle the gesture recognizers yourself.

Also, if this is for iOS8 I would be using the WKWebView instead.